# How to accumulate errors with ValidatedNec?

Tags: validation, scala-cats

I am trying to do a minimal error accumulation with cats validatedNec.
But it seems to fail compilation.
Here is the code I tried :

```scala
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
// doesn’t work with or without this line : import cats.syntax.applicative._

    val one: ValidatedNec[String, Int] = Validated.valid(42)
    val two: ValidatedNec[String, Boolean] = Validated.valid(true)
    (one, two).mapN{
      (one, two) => println(one)
    }
```

The error is : value mapN is not a member of (cats.data.ValidatedNec[String,…

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you're importing `cats.implicits._`, you're already importing all of the `syntax` extension, therefore, there's no need to import `cats.syntax.applicative`. To make things worse, when you import something twice in Scala, they will clash and leave you with nothing (since the Scala compiler can't choose which of the two to take)

If you remove that syntax import, it should work no problems.
See the import guide for more on this: https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/imports.html

Comment: Same problem without the line.

Comment: @Jhon_ do you have `-Ypartial-unification` enabled? Because that code works for me, see this fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/fdZUXtE/0